# How to solve swap pairs question in doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am having problems with a *swap pairs* function. Here you have to swap two adjacent nodes but it's showing *segmentation fault*.
I have declared a *before* `node *` and `after` and then I iterated through the loop:
`before` will move two steps and `after` will move 1 step ahead the `before` node.
When `before` will reach null we will get the required list but it's not showing results.
Your advice would be very helpful;

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node(int d)
    {
        this->data=d;
        this->next=nullptr;
    }
};

class ll
{
    private:
    node *head=nullptr;
    node *tail=nullptr;
    public:
    void inserthead(int value)
    {
        node *newnode=new node(value);
        if(head==nullptr)
        {
            head=newnode;
            tail=newnode;
        }
        else{
            newnode->next=head;
            head=newnode;
        }
    }
    void inserttail(int value)
    {
        node *newnode=new node(value);
        if(tail==nullptr)
        {
            head=newnode;
            tail=newnode;
        }
        else{
            tail->next=newnode;
            tail=newnode;
        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        node *temp=head;
        while(temp!=nullptr)
        {
            cout<<endl<<temp->data<<endl;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    void swap_pair()
    {
        node *before=head;
        while(before!=nullptr)
        {   
            node* after=before->next;
            int temp=before->value;
            before->value=after->value;
            after->value=temp;
            before=before->next->next;
        }
    }
};  
int main()
{
    ll l1;
    l1.inserthead(2);
    l1.inserthead(1);
    l1.inserttail(3);
    l1.inserttail(4);
    l1.swap_pair();
    l1.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting output `2 1 4 3`.

Comment: You've asked a question before, but haven't given feedback to the answers you got.

Comment: Unrelated: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` [loads the gun](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/4581301). `using namespace std;` [takes the safety off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/4581301). It is now really easy to shoot yourself in the foot, so **don't do this**. Tell whoever you learned it from.  If you got it off a website,  consider taking what they teach with a grain of salt because they could be passing on even worse information.

Comment: I have answered this to their previous question, and here we are. Doesn't seem to register somehow...

Comment: I didn't even need to use a debugger to find the likely issue, just some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @SAMRAT SARKAR First of all there is no doubly linked list in the presented code.:)

Comment: @SAMRAT SARKAR And where is there the name value declared?

Comment: Note that the code presented does *not* attempt to swap `node`s: it tries to swap associated data. With `head` & `next` public, *aliases* could be all over the place, with uncontrollable results.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small error. `value` should be `data`, because your `node` doesn't have `value` defined.

```
while(before!=nullptr)
{   
     node* after=before->next;
     int temp=before->data;
     before->data=after->data;
     after->data=temp;
     before=before->next->next;
}
```

It works for me after making this change.

As others have pointed out, I would highly recommend using a debugger to find these types of errors.

Finally, with *doubly linked lists* each node would need the ability to go forward and backwards. Yours only has "next", which means it's just a singly linked list.

Comment: You dereference `after`: How do you know it isn't `nullptr`?